# Can I replace the verb 'state' with 'express'?

Tags: verbs, word-difference

Is it possible to replace the word 'state' with 'express?' Do they mean the same? If not, what's the difference.

Example:

> I want to 'express **or** state' what happened yesterday

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verb *state* is firmer as compared to *express.* That said, if you 'state' something, [you are pretty firm on it and you are definite about it.](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/state)

On the other hand, if you 'express' something, it is more of your [feelings](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/express). There could be *an emotional touch in it.*

Don't ever try to interchange them before confirming it from authentic sources. For example, you can *express* your gratitude toward someone/thing, you don't *state* it!

The best thing you can do is learn from the examples given in the dictionaries.